# Easiest way to watch all calls in a .NET application (profiling / instrumentation)

Tags: .net, profiling, instrumentation, il

I'm trying to write a .NET application that can profile other .NET processes and list all the calls that have been made by them including the values of the passed parameters.

I understand that writing my own profiler with something like "ICorProfilerCallback2" can help on this but it seems like a quite challenging task. Before undertaking it I want to be sure that's the only way to do this.

I looked into open source .NET profilers and alike such as part-cover, CLR Profiler v4.0 etc. but none of them seems like provide a managed API to do this, and they do much more than what I need (memory profiling etc.).

Is there any other way to do this? An easier way to do this kind of profiling? What are my options in here?

Comment: Do you actually need to see "all" calls? Or just the *key* calls? Maybe something like mini-profiler could help, but I'm also thinking "PostSharp" here...

Comment: @MarcGravell The app that I'm going to profile is not mine, so I don't think Postsharp can do it.

Comment: Not sure if this is really an API, but SlimTune has at least some sort of plugin capability...

Comment: @MarcGravell I wonder if this can be done by using Postsharp and some IL weaving tool. i.e. Mono Cecil to inject Postsharp attributes (although AFAIK this will require generating new binaries before profiling)

Comment: How about extending WinDbg instead? :-)

Comment: The calls you need to watch, are they between assemblies or do you need to observe calls within the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

We once wrote such a tool using [Mono Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil).

With Cecil you can emit IL code into existing assemblies. This way you can add calls to a managed DLL of yours at the beginning of each method.

However the IL-injection is quite tricky as there are many cases to consider, but it is feasible. On the bright side: Once your managed DLL was called all your code can be written in a high-level way (e.g. C#), so the "only" tricky part is weaving the calls to your API.

A workflow using Cecil instrumentation could look like this:

1. Get your binaries (either build them or download)
2. Instrument them with your own post-compiler that uses Cecil
3. Run the modified assemblies which in turn call your managed DLL
4. Your DLL stores or analyses the data